# Запись дерева в файл и восстановление

Tags: c++, c, файлы

После записи/восстановления дерева из файла я запускаю функцию вывода дерева на консоль и у меня вылетает. До вылета видно, что на консоль выведен корень, один элемент второго уровня, два элемента третьего и элементы 4-го уровня, но только у одного элемента третьего. Проще говоря консоль вылетает когда идет попытка вывода элементов 4-го уровня второго элемента третьего. Не знаю в чем ошибка. Элементы 4-го уровня хранятся в виде односвязного списка.

```
void storeTree(FILE *f){
    fwrite(root,sizeof(NTrade),1,f);
    Seller *sAr = root->sellerArray;
    for(int i = 0; i < root->sellerCount; i++){
        fwrite(&sAr[i], sizeof(Seller),1, f);
        Product* *pAr = sAr[i].pProductArray;
        for(int j = 0; j < sAr[i].productCount; j++){
            fwrite(pAr[j], sizeof(Product), 1, f);
            Realiz *pR = pAr[j]->firstRealiz;
            while(pR != NULL){
                fwrite(pR, sizeof(Realiz), 1, f);
                pR = pR->nextRealiz;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void restoreTree(FILE *f){
    if(root != NULL)
        delTree(root);
    root = new NTrade;
    fread(root,sizeof(NTrade),1,f);
    root->sellerArray = new Seller [root->arCapacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < root->sellerCount; i++){
        fread(&root->sellerArray[i], sizeof(Seller), 1, f);
        Seller *se = &root->sellerArray[i];
        se->parent = root;
        se->pProductArray = new Product*[se->arCapacity];
        for(int j = 0; j < se->productCount; j++){
            Product *pr = new Product();
            fread(pr, sizeof(Product), 1, f);
            pr->parent = se;
            se->pProductArray[j] = pr;
            if(pr->firstRealiz != NULL){
                Realiz *rl = new Realiz();
                fread(rl, sizeof(Realiz), 1,  f);
                rl->parent = pr;
                pr->firstRealiz = rl;
                while(rl->nextRealiz != NULL){
                    Realiz *rlnxt = new Realiz();
                    fread(rlnxt, sizeof(Realiz), 1, f);
                    rlnxt->parent = pr;
                    rl->nextRealiz = rlnxt;
                    rl = rl->nextRealiz;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1277143/281034

Comment: там ответ на мой вопрос не дан. я изменил код, сейчас ошибка другая.

Comment: попробуйте запустить под отладчиком.

Comment: у меня урезанная версия QT, в ней нет отладчика :-(

Comment: А в файле что лежит после сохранения?

Comment: Ну должно лежать дерево, данные то записывались с дерева.

Comment: Может у вас некорректно записалось, Почему в earnings число минусовое внизу фото?

Comment: Также вы не выложили код вывода дерева.

Comment: Вывод работает правильно. А вот запись возможно не правильно. Код записи и восстановления я написал в этой теме.

Comment: Почему вы считаете что вывод работает правильно если вылет происходит как раз на выводе?

Comment: Судя по структурам данных, которые благодаря ссылке в первом комментарии можно увидеть (и то не все), уже ясно, что вы себе не представляете как работать с бинарными файлами и т.н. **записями** (records). Всё-таки начинать с Паскаля -- это правильное решение для обучения программированию.

Comment: @0andriy, а паскаль-то тут причем?

Comment: @0andriy, ну если вы видите ошибку, то почему вы не напишите варианты решения? Или вы зашли сюда просто написать о важности паскаля? Первый вопрос насчет записи дерева в файл я задал около 14 дней назад, все еще нет ответа. Не понимаю таких людей, которые просто пишут на какие-то другие темы под моим вопросом. Я спрашиваю об ошибке в моем коде, а не важности других языков. Если вы знаете что не так в моем коде, то я буду благодарен за помощь, а если нет, то прошу не писать тут на другие темы, мне в данный момент это не интересно.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, вывод дерева на консоль работает правильно, поскольку я писал все функции работы с деревом и не однократно проверял вывод. У меня возникли проблемы лишь с записью и восстановлением из файла, поскольку у меня в этом очень мало опыта. Ошибку нужно искать в этих двух функциях.

Comment: @luseppe, а вы пробывали выключить весь вывод и произвести операции записи \восстановления дерева? Если вылета не будет значит виновата функция вывода.

Comment: Трогательный комментарий, однако. Если вы хотите решения, обратитесь к профессионалам за деньги, зачем вы пишете на ruSO в таком случае? Не пишите сюда.

Comment: @0andriy, вот об этом я и говорил. Вы сами не понимаете что тут не так и даете глупые советы. Обратился я сюда, потому что я хочу услышать подсказку, а не получить готовую работу.

Comment: Это как раз настойчивость в том, что «в этих функциях надо искать ошибку» при так и неисправленном коде показывает непонимание происходящего. Программирование — это прежде всего про **структуры данных**, а не про код. Многие этого не понимают, к превеликому сожалению.

Comment: @0andriy, ну скажу вам так, я уже нашел саму ошибку и частично исправил. Ошибка была именно в этих функциях, как я и писал. В остальных я уверен, поскольку неоднократно до этого проверял их, в том числе и вывод списка. Если вы не видите ошибку в коде и пишите о паскале, то мне не о чем с вами говорить.

Comment: Супер! Опубликуете ответ?

Comment: @0andriy после сдачи работы.